# How to identify the same tab or fragment when change tabs on tablayout?

Tags: android

The layout is simple, tablayout and viewpager below. And we use fragment in viewpager. There is an animation in the fragment. Now each time we change the tab, new fragment is shown and The animation shows. I want to cancel the animation if I change tab back to the same tab. For example, tab 1 , changed to tab2 and then go back to tab 1, the first visit to tab 1, animation shows, but the second visit to tab 1, animation should be canceled.  How to do that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can add a boolean variable with initial value false and after first time you can change its value to true and inside onAnimationEnd listner.then next time animation shown only is boolean false.

```
boolean isAnimationShown = false;
    animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            isAnimationShown = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: I'm sorry I clicked the wrong arrive. I was thinking of thumbs up. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to play the things in-

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                // save the current position and last position of the pager.
                // and check accordingly what you want to achieve.

            }
            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
```

Sorry for the terse reply.